# Enzyme simulate click event which makes API calls not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

In one of my projects, [React-Instagram-Clone-2.0](http://github.com/yTakkar/React-Instagram-Clone-2.0), I've added a feature which enables users to add other users to favourites.

I have a test which simulates click event done on the button which makes a POST request and adds user to favs. But it's doesn't reach the server and the test always passes.

Here is the code.

**Add-to-favourites.js**

```
const AddToFavourites = ({ user, username }) => {

let add = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  addToFavourites(user)   // util function
  new d('.af_btn').blur()
}

return (
  <div>
    <div className='recomm_teaser'>
      <span>Wanna add {username} to your favourites list.</span>
      <SecondaryButton
        label='Add'
        onClick={add}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

**addToFavourites function**

```
export const addToFavourites = async user => {
  let {
    data: { success, mssg }
  } = await post('/api/add-to-favourites', { user }) // POST request

  if (success) {
    insta_notify({
      to: user,
      type: 'favourites'
    })
  }

  console.log('Test debugging')  // Never logged
  // But I remove the request, The above message is logged out.
  Notify({ value: mssg })
  }
```

**And my test file**

```
describe('AddToFavourites Component', () => {

const comp = (
  <AddToFavourites
    user={7}
    username='ghalib'
  />
)

it('should match snapshot', () => {
  const tree = create(comp).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})

it('should add user to favs when clicked', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(comp)

  wrapper.find('SecondaryButton').simulate(
    'click',
    { preventDefault() {} }
  )

  expect(true).toBe(true)
 })

})
```

Any solution?

Thnx in advance :)

Comment: you seems to need to handle async flow. try mark test as `async` and pass `done` arg - you'll see an error that `done` never calls, however let's check if you'll see `console.log`: `it('should add user to favs when clicked', async (done) => {`

Comment: also, what is `post()`? How do you include it?

Comment: If you consider this a unit test, you should not be calling a external url, either mock it or test another part of the code not involving it. Integration tests should do this before, but the first line of testing is unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I could see several issues in your code. First issue is you're using async method. So it's highly likely test reach its end before API call is resolved. You could fix it with `setTimeout`:

```
it('should add user to favs when clicked', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(comp)

  wrapper.find('SecondaryButton').simulate(
    'click',
    { preventDefault() {} }
  )

  setTimeout(() => console.log("I'm dirty js hack"), 4500)

  expect(true).toBe(true)
 })

})
```

Here is 4500ms used because of internal Jest limit with 5000ms. But you could expand it with settings, so you'll see second issue.

It is in your relative path to API. I don't think jest runs on `localhost`, so you won't be able to reach the server. You'll need to mock request to the server, but I think it is [covered in documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async). Though I think you won't be able to avoid setTimeout because API call is proceed internally.